# toggleClass() not working in firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm using this piece of jquery code to toggle the header class when the page is scrolled past certain sections, but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox. What's wrong with it?

```
//toggle header class
var whiteSections = $(".our-products, .our-clients, .team, .about-us");
var header = $("header");

$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop + 90;
    var scrollBottom = document.body.scrollTop - 90;
    var dark = false;
    whiteSections.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var top = $this.offset().top;
        if (top <= scrollTop && top + $this.height() >= scrollBottom) {
            dark = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    header.toggleClass("dark", dark);
});
```

Comment: but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox? what about other browsers? working on them? can you create a link so that we can check the problem

Comment: Works in other browsers and I just figured out it also doesn't work in IE. The project is still in local production so I can't provide a link.